# KSQL Server connects to Remote Kafka Cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I'm using a local KSQL Server (latest version of Confluent Platform), trying to connect to a Tunneled Kafka cluster on my server (AWS). However, I'm facing an issue of cannot start KSQL server because of the below error:

```
ERROR Failed to initialize TopicClient: Unexpected broker id, expected 5 or empty string, but received ConfigResource(type=BROKER, name='1').name (io.confluent.ksql.services.KafkaTopicClient:279)
ERROR Failed to start KSQL (io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain:53)
io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlException: Could not fetch broker information. KSQL cannot initialize
    at 
io.confluent.ksql.services.KafkaTopicClientImpl.isTopicDeleteEnabled (KafkaTopicClientImpl.java:280)
    at io.confluent.ksql.services.KafkaTopicClientImpl.<init>(KafkaTopicClientImpl.java:66)
    at io.confluent.ksql.services.DefaultServiceContext.create(DefaultServiceContext.java:43)
    at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlRestApplication.buildApplication(KsqlRestApplication.java:303)
    at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain.createExecutable(KsqlServerMain.java:85)
    at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain.main(KsqlServerMain.java:50)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidRequestException: Unexpected broker id, expected 5 or empty string, but received ConfigResource(type=BROKER, name='1').name
```

My tunneled kafka cluster is running on the version 2.0.0. Even I tried to use the previous version of KSQL (5.0.x) that's compatible with the Kafka version 2.0.x. However the issue still happen.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the Kafka cluster from your local machine using another Kafka client, such as `kafkacat`, `kafka-console-consumer`, etc?

Comment: I thought it works well on my Java Application, however it seems it doesn't

`Marking the coordinator stage-0001-kafka-05:9092 (id: 2147483642 rack: null) dead`
`2019-03-19T11:52:53.968-04:00 INFO  [pool-1-thread-2] - (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator,common.utils.LogContext$KafkaLogger:341) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=localExecutorGroup] Discovered coordinator stage-0001-kafka-05:9092 (id: 2147483642 rack: null)`

Comment: If you can't connect with a standard Kafka client then you won't be able to with KSQL either. For networking config tips see https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: Thanks @RobinMoffatt I will take a look the link and try to figure it out.

Comment: hi @RobinMoffatt, I tried to use `kafkacat` tool, and I can get the metadata by the command below
`kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -L`

Comment: I finally understand everything here. So technically, there are multiple nodes in Kafka cluster (5 nodes), I did a tunnel to connect to node-02, but the metadata returns the leader is node-05. that's why even I did update my host file /etc/hosts to map the node-05 DNS to my local IP, but Kafka returns the error
`This server is not the leader for that topic-partition`

I fixed it by changing my tunnel to use node-05, so my tunnel is using leader as well. The issue has been resolved. 

Thanks for providing the helpful documentation @RobinMoffatt

Comment: Below is the command I have used to test and see the error detail
`echo "test"|./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic events`

Comment: I still get the same error as in my question whilst running KSQL. I tested the command below, it works well:
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --partition 1 --from-beginning

Comment: @RobinMoffatt any advises from you?

Comment: It sounds like you're setting up a tunnel to only one Kafka broker. However, ksqlDB and any other Kafka client would need to be able to talk to ALL the Kafka brokers.

Comment: What's more, any Kafka client will bootstrap its list of Kafka brokers from the first broker it connects to.  That broker will tell it the addresses of all the other brokers.  It's crucial that the addresses the broker shares to bootstrap the clients is resolvable and routable by the client host. 

You can configure the address each broker shares with clients by setting [advertised.listeners](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#advertised.listeners)